# What should the Length/Value be for "DATE" data type in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, date

I looked for the answer to this question before posting this but I couldn't find it. I'm sorry if it has been asked before but I would like to know what I should enter for the Length/Value for "DATE" in mysql.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to provide a length. Just do:

```
create table test (
 id int,
 created_date date,
 modified_date date
);
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-syntax.html for documentation.

You can insert data with `insert into test values (1, '2020-01-01', '2020-02-01');`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are referring to this?  `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` have an *optional* length.  It refers to the number of decimal places (up to 6) for fractional seconds.  Certain other functions also have this convention:

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(), NOW(6);
+---------------------+----------------------------+
| NOW()               | NOW(6)                     |
+---------------------+----------------------------+
| 2021-12-10 22:56:14 | 2021-12-10 22:56:14.927507 |
+---------------------+----------------------------+
```

(But, I don't think you need the parens on `DATETIME`.)